# What BURG Themes are Available

Tags: themes, burg

What BURG Themes are Available?

- [How do I install burg themes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50646/how-do-i-install-burg-themes/50647#50647)

Answer (score 3):

## [Lightness](http://sworiginal.deviantart.com/art/Lightness-for-burg-181461810)

[image]

> Called 'Lightness' the theme was designed to feel 'calm, clean & modern' according to its designer, and certainly gives a beautifully minimalistic introduction to your boot time.

Answer (score 2):

### [Metro](http://luxieblack.deviantart.com/art/Metro-burg-theme-336505408)

[image: Burg Metro theme]

> A Windows 8/Metro inspired Burg theme.

Answer (score 1):

### [Radiance](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Ubuntu+Radience+for+Grub+2+%5BBURG%5D?content=121105)

[image]

Keep the common look and feel from boot to desktop

Answer (score 0):

## [achromatic](http://sworiginal.deviantart.com/art/achromatic-for-burg-185572713?q=gallery:sworiginal&qo=0)

[image]